# Error en un .bat con el final de mes

Tags: cmd, batch, línea-de-comandos, .bat, msdos

con ayudas y lecturas varias, pude armar un bat que toma la fecha actual del sistema y le resta 1 dia, si por el formato del equipo, el mes ó el día de esa fecha tiene 1 solo digito, les agrego un "0" por delante, y lo guardo en las variables d y m . Tambien lo propio con el año en "y".
Luego cree varios if para que según el mes me de el valor o número del último día.
La fecha completa, la cargo en una variable y le agrego la extensión .reg , luego busco en una carpeta de red un archivo con ese nombre.reg exacto ( ejemplo 03122021.reg ), la idea es "siempre" traer el archivo cuyo nombre corresponde al día anterior al actual, luego copio, lo muevo,etc.

```html
@echo off
set /a d=%date:~0,2%
set /a m=%date:~3,2%
set /a y=%date:~6,4%
set /a d-=1

if %d% LSS 10 set d=0%d%
if %m% LSS 10 set m=0%m%

if %m% == 01 set FinMes=31
if %m% == 02 set FinMes=28
if %m% == 03 set FinMes=31
if %m% == 04 set FinMes=30
if %m% == 05 set FinMes=31
if %m% == 06 set FinMes=30
if %m% == 07 set FinMes=31
if %m% == 08 set FinMes=31
if %m% == 09 set FinMes=30
if %m% == 10 set FinMes=31
if %m% == 11 set FinMes=30
if %m% == 12 set FinMes=31

if %d% EQU 01 (
set d=%FinMes%
set /a m-=1

if %m% == 01 (
set m=12
set /a y-=1
)
)


set archivo=%y%%m%%d%
echo %archivo%

Set Orig= "M:\BACK\Control\backup\%archivo%.reg"
Set Dest= "C:\Base\Files\."
Set backup="M:\BACK\Control\backup\pasados\."

XCOPY %Orig% %Dest% /Y
@ECHO.Proceso finalizado - Fecha : %date% - Hora : %time:~0,8% - File : %archivo% >> procesos.log
cd /D "M:\BACK\Control\backup\"
FOR %%a in (%archivo%.reg) do call :REG %%a
EXIT

:REG
if exist M:\BACK\Control\backup\pasados\%1 (
echo. >> M:\BACK\Control\backup\pasados\%1
type %1 >> M:\BACK\Control\backup\pasados\%1
del %1
) else (
move %1 %backup%
)
```

Cada fin de mes la rutina falla, no trae lo esperado, podrían ayudarme a encontrar el error? Gracias !

Comment: Cada fin de mes ?= en el último día? en el día 1 del mes siguiente, que debe buscar el FinMes? Por favor, especifica un poquitito más el fallo

Comment: esta rutina corre diariamente 1 vez, toma la fecha del dia 07122021 , le resta 1 día y quedaría 06122021 , le agrega la extension .reg , queda 06122021.reg , y va a buscar ese archivo a una unidad de red.  Cuando es 1º de mes , 01122021 al restar 1 día deberia quedar 30112021 , pero arma mal el nombre de archivo , cuando sea 01012022 al restar deberia quedar 31122021 . Despues ese archivo lo proceso, pero lo mas importante es que traiga el archivo correcto. Intenté que reconozca el ultimo dia del mes anterior con los IF , pero algo estoy haciendo mal ..  se entiende mejor ? voy de nuevo si no

Comment: cuando no es 1ero de mes funciona correcto, o sea. del 2 al último día de cada mes va ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que tienes es porque deberías verificar si el día es 1 y luego hacer la resta. O si prefieres, hacer la resta primero pero el día que debes verificar es 0. Lo mismo pasa con el mes.

Cambiando esta parte así debería bastar:

```
if %d% EQU 0 (
    set d=%FinMes%
    set /a m-=1

    if %m% EQU 0 (
        set m=12
        set /a y-=1
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás haciendo

```
set /a d-=1
```

antes de revisar si el día actual es 01 o qué es. Yo le haría debug a la expresión y revisaría si está quedando `00`, por lo que ni entraría al IF ni encontraría ningún archivo